# jQuery Use animate() to animate height of div to hide/reveal content inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slidedown, slideup

I am attempting to animate the height of a div to hide or reveal the content inside of it. Using animate() is the most convenient way to get the animation that I would like as you are able to specify a height to animate it to. However, I am attempting to get the functionality of using slideUp() or slideDown(). When using animate() for the height, the content inside of the div id pushed up or down depending on whether you are shrinking or expanding the height...this is not what I want. I would like the div to slide up and hide the content inside or slide down and reveal it (almost like a garage door opening or closing and revealing or hiding the content inside, not affecting it in any way as if it had a fixed position). Is there a clean way to do this? I would just go ahead and use slideUp() and slideDown() but I need to be able to specify a height to grow to and a height to stop at. Any help is appreciated.

**Here is a fiddle of a full working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8XRqg/

Here is a version of what I am trying to do with jQuery. I have it exactly as it needs to function, only I **do not** want the content to be affected by the shrinking of the divs. Also, I now have the content fade out when switching between the top and bottom sections. I want to get rid of that once the functionality is how I want it.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        var top = $("#top");
        var bottom = $("#bottom");
        var image = $(".image");
        var content = $(".content");
        var topOpen = false;
        var bottomOpen = false;

        content.hide();

        top.click(function()
        {
            if(topOpen == false)
            {   
                var thisContent = $(this).children(".content");
                topOpen = true;
                bottomOpen = false;
                content.fadeOut(250);
                thisContent.css({ marginTop : (thisContent.height()/2) * -1 });

                image.fadeOut("fast", function()
                {
                    thisContent.delay(500).fadeIn(250);
                    top.animate({ height : 190 });
                    bottom.animate({ height : 10 });
                });
            }
        });

        bottom.click(function()
        {   
            if(bottomOpen == false)
            {
                var thisContent = $(this).children(".content");
                bottomOpen = true;
                topOpen = false;
                content.fadeOut(250);
                thisContent.css({ marginTop : (thisContent.height()/2) * -1 });

                image.fadeOut("fast", function()
                {   
                    thisContent.delay(500).fadeIn(250);
                    bottom.animate({ height : 190 });
                    top.animate({ height : 10 });
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: in this little video-game, how you go back to start screen?

Comment: The extent to which content is affected during slideUp()/slideDown() animations (and similar as in your case) is determined by the CSS applied to the contained elements, not by the jQuery that performs the animation.

Comment: Essentially, make sure that none of the contained elements has either a height or a position that depends on the container's height.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following url for help. I feel you are looking for something like this.

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#default

Comment: this is your subjective suggestion, and in none part of it you're trying to answer the exact question. Best suited for a *Question comment* instead.

Comment: Thats not really what I am trying to do in the link. I am trying to do something along the lines as if you had a div A inside of div B if you use slideUp() on div B, div A would be hidden but would not move at all.

Comment: @user2227738 I'm still not able to understand you. If I see your code, you have 2 blocks 'top' and 'bottom', each having an image and some lines of text. What is the functionality/experience you are looking at?

Comment: I am attempting to have it function exactly as it does only the way that I would like it is if one of the divs – top or bottom – is clicked after they have been opened (when you can see the content) instead of having the content shrink with its parent div, I would like the parent div to animate over the content (right now the content animates with the parent div and shrinks). I would like the content to stay positioned where it is and have the parent div slide over it to either reveal it (if opened) or hide it (if closed).

Comment: @user2227738 Please find the fiddle here. I guess this help. <http://jsfiddle.net/ardeezstyle/DaYx5/>

Comment: I think people are still confused about what I am trying to do. I guess forget everything that I have said before. If you check out this fiddle and: **1.** Click either of the divs (top or bottom) to reveal the content. **2.** Click the closed div to reveal the content that is inside of that one. **3.** Watch the content of the div that is currently open as its parent div slide up...the content moves. I want the content to stay exactly where it is unaffected by the div sliding closed...I want the div to slide closed on top of the content to hide it. http://jsfiddle.net/8XRqg/

Comment: I guess there is something wrong in my understanding. Please help yourself, I'm leaving this con.